# ¿Como detectar el nodo padre de un window.getSelection()?

Tags: javascript, html, extensión-google-chrome

Estoy haciendo una extension para chrome que sustituye el texto seleccionado en una pagina por plantillas predefinidas por el usuario.

En general va bien, y reemplaza el texto en cualquier parte de la pagina, incluyendo el cuerpo de los mensajes de Gmail, que era el proposito original, pero cuando la selección se encuentra dentro de un textarea no funciona, imagino que porque el interior de un textarea no forma parte del DOM propiamente dicho.

¿Como podría detectar si el texto seleccionado está dentro de un textarea para en ese caso sustituirlo de otra forma?.
Aqui el código relevante:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request) {
        console.log("recibo");
        fill(request.texto);
    }
);

function fill(plant) {
    var mitext = window.getSelection()
    var res = plant.replace(/#/g, mitext);
    var sel, range;
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();
        range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(res));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya he conseguido discriminar si se trata de un textarea para actuar en consecuencia con `document.activeElement` pego el código final:

```
function fill(plant) {
   var mitext = window.getSelection()
   var res = plant.replace(/#/g, mitext);
   var sel = window.getSelection();
   if (document.activeElement.tagName == "TEXTAREA") {
       $(document.activeElement).val(res);
   } else {
       if (sel.rangeCount) {
           var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
           range.deleteContents();
           range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(res));
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Empiezaría por escribir

```
var textAreas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea')
```

luego algo como

```
textAreas.forEach(function (textArea) {
  if (textArea.value.indexOf(plantilla) != -1) { // la prueba
    textArea.style.color = 'red' // lo que quieras hacer aquí con textArea
  }
})
```

o en un evento onchange por ejemplo:

```
var plantilla
document.querySelectorAll('textarea').forEach(function (textArea) {
  textArea.addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (this.value.indexOf(plantilla) != -1) { // la prueba
      this.style.color = 'red' // lo que quieras hacer aquí con textArea
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Hola, creo que no me he explicado bien, yo selecciono con el raton el texto que quiero modificar y pulso el boton de la extension. Funciona salvo cuando el texto seleccionado esta en un textarea, que no reemplaza el contenido de su interior.
De todas formas he encontrado como resolverlo, 
 con `document.activeElement;`puedo ver si el texto seleccionado está dentro de un textarea y sustituirlo con `.value` en vez de con `insertNode`

Comment: Lo has pillado, el interior del textarea esta en `.value` no es un `textNode`